# How to calculate avg earnings/hour spent working by day of week?

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a query to output the average earnings per hour spent dashing by day of week.

worker_table

| session_id | worker_id | session_start | session_end | total_pay | num_of_deliveries |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7712 | 9347 | 2020-08-31 03:32:43 | 2020-08-31 05:53:43 | 46.72 | 3 |
| 1560 | 5645 | 2020-07-26 01:48:40 | 2020-07-26 04:48:40 | 65.32 | 4 |

This is my query below but I am 99% positive it's incorrect. Please advise, thanks.

```
with t1 as 
(select extract(dow from session_start) as dow, extract(hour from session_start) as start_hours, extract(hour from session_end) as end_hours, sum(total_pay) as total_pay  
from worker_table
group by 1,2,3)

select dow, total_pay/(end_hours-start_hours)
from t1
order by 1
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

Try datediff function SQL Server

```
Select total_pay/DateDiff(hh,session_start,session_end),*
From table_name
```

Replace table_name with your table name in the database.